# STD Exception encountered while processing chain.get_account when requesting get_account

Tags: nodeos, api

I'm trying to get account info by posting to **/v1/chain/get_account**

But I'm getting the following error:

```
STD Exception encountered while processing chain.get_account
Exception Details: unknown key
```

POST data is

```
{
    "account_name": "gy3dgnbsgige"
}
```

I've also been trying to get balances by posting to **/v1/chain/get_currency_balance** and have been getting the following error:

```
FC Exception encountered while processing chain.get_currency_balance
Exception Details: 3060002 account_query_exception: Account Query Exception
Fail to retrieve account for eosblackteam
{"account":"eosblackteam"}
thread-0  chain_plugin.cpp:970 get_abi
```

POST data is

```
{
    "account": "gy3dgnbsgige",
    "symbol": "BLACK",
    "code": "eosblackteam"
}
```

Config is similar to this: [config.ini](https://github.com/CryptoLions/EOS-MainNet/blob/master/config.ini).
Version is 1.1.1 built from master branch.

Run command:

```
nodeosd.sh --data-dir /opt/eosio/bin/data-dir --replay-blockchain --hard-replay-blockchain -e --http-alias=0.0.0.0:8888 --http-validate-host=false
```

I've tried making these requests to a public node (*api1.eosdublin.io*) and they work.

Anyone know why this is happening? Do I need something specific in config.ini to enable this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused with account_name. Here, I can see two different names `gy3dgnbsgige` and `eosblackteam`. So, make sure you are using the correct account name which you created by using `cleos create account eosio <your-account-name>` command.

By looking at this error `Exception Details: unknown key`, I think `gy3dgnbsgige` is not your account name.

HTH.